# Mat-Timepicker doesn't display when build --prod

Tags: angular, npm, production

I'm using [mat-timepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-timepicker) v5.1.5 and it works **locally**.

But when I **build the app for production and deploy** on Tomcat server, the **timepicker do not display**. I don't get any error when `build --prod` neither on server side or browser console.

**I tried many versions** of mat-timepicker but I keep getting the same result.

Here's my environment :

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.10
Node: 14.17.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.16
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.6.3
@angular-devkit/core               7.3.10
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.3.10
@angular/cdk                       7.3.7
@angular/cli                       7.3.10
@angular/flex-layout               7.0.0-beta.24
@angular/material                  7.3.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                   6.0.3
@schematics/angular                7.3.10
@schematics/update                 0.13.10
rxjs                               6.5.3
typescript                         3.1.6
webpack                            4.8.3
```

If you have any idea of what's going on it'll be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a descent result using [ngx-material-timepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker) and this is how I implemented it :

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-2">
    <input matInput placeholder="Start" [ngxTimepicker]="startPicker" name="start" [format]="24"
              [value]="myForm.value.start" formControlName="start" readonly>
    <ngx-material-timepicker #startPicker></ngx-material-timepicker>
    <mat-error *ngIf="interventionForm.controls['start'].errors?.check">Error message
    </mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Hope that can help someone.